# Cannot create an instance of "MainViewModel"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am creating a simple WPFapplication for implementing Databinding a Datagrid to database using Observable collection (following MVVM pattern).

App.xaml.cs class

```
public partial class App : Application
 {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

when I try to bind it to my XAML I have the following error raised :

**Cannnot create an instance of "MainViewModel"**

XAML code :

```
  <Window x:Class="MVVM_DemoAppl.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MVVM_DemoAppl.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <!-- The error is raised here -->
   <Window.DataContext> 
     <ViewModel:MainViewModel/> 
   </Window.DataContext>
```

how to overcome this error ? Thanks.

P.S : I have posted the same question on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b5d4520c-7d36-4666-987f-b993e7e015b6) but with my entire code, kindly have a look for better understanding.

On user's suggestion, do I have to keep my OnStartup() in this way ?

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No. I am not using stacktrace

Comment: If you're not going to set any properties or what not in the code behind (in the `Startup()` function), it is sufficient to define it in the XAML. That line of code will create a new MainViewModel

Comment: @userXemY Point of information: "A [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)  is a report of the active stack frames at a certain point in time during the execution of a program."

Comment: @Default could you please describe as a code block. I can't get you

Comment: I'm basically saying that you can remove the code in your `Startup()` function and it would work.

Comment: I am afraid that if I remove the code inside the Startup() function, it's not gonna work. I have the same err getting displayed

Comment: You are creating a MainViewModel instance twice, once in OnStartup() and once when defining the DataContext in your xaml.

Comment: pls look at my edited question above, should I have to keep my OnStartup() like that ?

Comment: If you are not doing anything special in OnStartup there is no need to capture the event.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you comment out the code `initializeload();` in the `MainViewModel constructor`? I have a feeling that there is some error when you create your model/database/something else and that this is not an error in WPF specifically. If you *dont* get an error when you've commented that out, try to pinpoint the line of code that is generating the error. If you are using Visual Studio and get an exception you can open the Exception details via the "View Detail" link and check the Inner Exception(s). That should give you some clue as to where the issue actually is.

Comment: .. for instance, the line `Messages = table.Rows[i][3].ToString()             Critical = Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[i][1]),` seems misplaced in the `initializeload` function. Although, that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Default : I have changed the row number for Critical and when I comment the initializeload() in my MainViewModel. I have no errors, my output displays an empty datagrid.

Comment: @userXemY how about you visit the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) and we can work this out step by step. Otherwise I'd suggest you to start removing bits of code and see where the error comes from (I'd start in the `getData`function in your `Model`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the binding on the constructor of the MainWindow and remove it from the XAML:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

This should work ..

Comment: if I remove from XAML, how can I bind it to my ItemsSource in the datagrid?

Comment: You should remove only the DataContext setting from your XAML. The bindings are meant to be made on XAML

Comment: OK this works now, i replaced my DataContext with  
<Window.Resources>
<ViewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="EventLogData"/>
</Window.Resources> . I can see only an empty datagrid in the output

Comment: @userXemY that's because you haven't created that object! The `DataContext` is the context that the view uses to bind to, when you are defining it in your `Resources` it is not created. This would mean that you have no DataContext bound to your view which is why the datagrid is empty (and you should see that the bindings fail if you look in the Debug Output window). **You have to locate the error which is generated in the creation of the `ViewModel`**

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different ways of setting DataContext. Select one and go with that.

If your viewmodels have default constructors (i.e. constructors without arguments) you could do it all in xaml:

```
  <Window x:Class="MVVM_DemoAppl.Views.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MVVM_DemoAppl.ViewModels"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Window.DataContext>
         <! This instantiates a MainViewModel and binds this view to the viewmodel.
         <ViewModel:MainViewModel/> 
     </Window.DataContext>
```

Or you leave Window.DataContext be unset in your view and do it separately somewhere else, perhaps in OnStartup() as earlier.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
      var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
      mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel; // Bind the ViewModel to the Window Datacontext.
      mainWindow.Show();
   }
}
```